# How do I refactor this loop?

Tags: java, refactoring

I've got an application where I use primitive arrays and Lists for a class called *Item*. These are used interchangeably for legacy reasons (I also wish this was just one type, but it's the way it is).

Now I have to add a new method like this that works via a for-each loop:

```
public void something(Item... items) {
    for (Item i : items) {
        doStuff();
    }
}

public void something(List<Item> items) {
    for (Item i : items) {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

In other words, exactly the same method twice for both primitive Arrays and Lists. Is there any way to nicely refactor this into a single method?

Comment: i would prefer not to use `for-each` for `List` , it doesn't work

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi how does a `for-each` not work on `List` objects?

Comment: Uhh, why wouldn't it work? The code I got right here works fine, it's just not nicely refactored.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi that's a bold statement, care to explain why it should not work?

Comment: @AndyTurner the question says that the OP wants to refactor it into a single method, your solution would still have two methods.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134257/discussion-on-question-by-user3216060-how-do-i-refactor-this-loop).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You <s>can't</s> shouldn't (*) do this in a single method. `Item[]` and `List<Item>` are unrelated types.

You should make one of the overloads call the other: either `something(Item... items)` calls `something(List<Item>)`, or `something(List<Item>)` calls `something(Item... items)`.

Of the two options, it is better for the array overload to call the list overload:

```
public void something(Item... items) {
  something(Arrays.asList(item));
}
```

This is cheap, because it doesn't copy the array, but rather wraps it: creating the `List` is `O(1)`.

If you were to invoke the array overload from the list overload:

```
public void something(List<Item> items) {
  something(items.toArray(new Item[0]));
}
```

This would be more expensive, since the `toArray` call has to create and populate an array: it is an `O(n)` operation, where `n` is the size of the list. However, it has the slight advantage that `something` would not be able to replace the contents of the `List`, since any updates to the array are simply discarded after execution.

---

(*) You *can*, but it would be really gross, and not type-safe, as you'd have to accept an `Object` parameter, as there is no other common super type of `List<Item>` and `Item[]`; and you'd still end up having to repeat the loops for the two types; and you'd have to handle the possibility of a completely unrelated type being passed in (at runtime):

```
public void something(Object obj) {
  if (obj instanceof List) {
    for (Object element : (List<?>) obj) {
      Item item = (Item) element;  // Potential ClassCastException.
      doStuff();
    }
  } else if (obj instanceof Item[]) {
    for (Item item : (Item[]) obj) {
      doStuff();
    }
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

What a mess. Thank the maker for overloads.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing how you could do it, just out of curiosity. Edit: that makes sense, you'd have to have a conditional in there to figure out what type was being passed in.

Comment: @MichaelCurry read this part: " ... as you'd have to accept an `Object` parameter ... " - you'd basically check the type of the parameter inside the method and act accordingly. However, there's nothing to be gained by this as the code complexity as well as the fragility would rise (you could pass other things to that method as well, e.g. simple strings or numbers.

Comment: @MichaelCurry there you are.

Comment: Really not sure what to do here. The overhead with array conversion or the cancer that is that... thing with Object. :D

Comment: @user3216060 "because it **doesn't copy** the array," - the overhead is rather small.

Comment: Thank the maker for overloads indeed. @user3216060 reflection has some overhead too IIRC, although I'm not sure if reflecting just to get a class is that intensive. It really depends on your performance requirements I guess, but if I were you I'd just overload and write for twice, might not look pretty but it probably runs faster. Definitely **don't** do the one method taking in Object.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I thought it would create an exact duplicate of the list under a different structure (and this kind of list isn't exactly small in my application), so I wasn't sure how serious the impact of .asList is.

Comment: @user3216060 [Javadoc to the rescue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)): "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs".

Comment: @user3216060 I'd be curious if one vs. the other is 'more commonly' used, or perhaps one is treated as deprecated but still supported for legacy reasons?  If lists are the 'new' way of doing things (and any new code will be using lists), then this is a good solution to keep supporting arrays.  If new code will use arrays, and only older code would use lists, you might want to dual-implement (unless you could do the reverse of this and implement the list version as calling the array version?).

Answer (score 17):

If you use Java 8 you could also just call [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) or [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) on your [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and you are done, e.g.

```
yourStream.forEach(doStuff());
```

where `doStuff()` is the [consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) dealing with the String or use `yourStream.forEach(s -> doStuff())` if you don't want to handle the string and just `do stuff`.

You can obtain a stream as follows:

```
Stream.of(yourArray) // or Arrays.stream(yourArray)
      .forEach(doStuff());
```

and for your list:

```
list.stream()
    .forEach(doStuff());
```

The main benefit of using the streams is probably readability. It may lose regarding performance and it may also lose if you don't want to call `Stream.of/Arrays.stream` or `Collection.stream()` just to obtain the stream.

If you really want to keep the `something(...)` method (being able to deal with both: the varargs and the list) you are still requiring an overloaded method or use [Andy Turner's proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41897199/6202869) with the `Object`-parameter-method.

Comment: But you'd still have to have two overloaded methods to obtain a stream ... right?

Comment: yes, that's true. it is probably also just a matter of preference, readability and performance. I find streams most of the time more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a single method, in this case, the second one because it has a list as parameter. Instead of the first method, you can convert the array in a list with `Arrays.asList(items)` and then, you can call the first method. So, in the end, you will have only a single method (that has a list as parameter).

Also, if the items list has few elements, you can use the lambda expressions from Java 8:

```
items.foreach(item -> doStuff(item));
```

So, you will not have a method that contains only one loop and the code will be easier to read.

Comment: or even `items.foreach(ClassName::doStuff)`

Answer (score 0):

You should achieve this by passing List after converting it to array.

Retain this as your single method,

```
public void something(Item... items) {
   for (Item i : items) {
       doStuff();
   }
}
```

and when you want to pass a `List<Item>` then pass like this,

`something(listItem.toArray(new Item[listItem.size()]))`

Comment: As mentioned in the other post below, this works but brings in the overhead of having to convert the array first. I was hoping there was a way to do this "directly".

Comment: This is the wrong way round to do the conversion: this requires a copy of the array to be made; but changing an array to a list using `Arrays.toList` simply wraps the array without a copy. So, it's O(n) vs O(1).

Comment: Also, note that the current wisdom is that `new Item[0]` is actually more efficient than `new Item[listItem.size()]`. Looking for a reference...

Comment: @AndyTurner oh, really?? I thought it was the other way round! I'd honestly be interested in that reference. Does this depend on Java version (6/7/8)?

Comment: @Fildor it was a very detailed analysis that I can't find just now. As I recall, the reason was that the fact it's a constant length array allows JIT to do optimizations. That, and the fact it's less thread safe to use `list.size()`.

Comment: @Fildor On GrepCode all that .asList does is _literally_ just passing it to a constructor for ArrayList: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.asList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29

Comment: @user3216060 that is quite irrelevant, there is no invocation of `toArray` going on there. Note that isn't `java.util.ArrayList`, it's `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`.

Comment: I never said that, but in your other comment you made the complexity comparisons. I was wondering how this O(1) came to happen, and with this code it's kinda obvious. My initial assumption was that .asList would do the same thing that jack jay has posted here.

Comment: What I'm saying is, I had a generous misconception between *to*Array and *as*Array. I thought these terms were used interchangeably. :D

Comment: @AndyTurner Another day, another thing learned on SO. Thanks!