# Check if an instance is either an Array or a Collection in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, iterable

I want to create a method in Java that receives either an array or a collection, it does not matter, because all i do is iterate it. I don't want to create a list from the array because it would impact on the performance of the algorithm and i am really tired of always creating an overloading method for every method which accepts a List. Is there a convenient parent class for both, like "Iterable", or something?

Comment: *I don't want to create a list from the array because it would impact on the performance of the algorithm* Really?  By that much?

Comment: *"I don't want to create a list from the array because it would impact on the performance of the algorithm"* - Then don't, require the caller to do it. Make it so your API only consumes `Collection`s

Comment: You can treat any reference array as a list with `Arrays.asList()`. It's a very light wrapper class.

Comment: See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897133/how-do-i-refactor-this-loop/41897199#41897199). TL;DR: don't try to do this with a single method, wrap the array with `Arrays.asList` and pass to the other method.

Comment: @JoeC suppose the array has 10^9 elements in it. Is there a solution O(1) or at least O(logN) for this?

Comment: Yes. `Arrays.asList` wraps the existing array.  It doesn't copy it over.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would like to create something generic, to put on a Lib, or a framework etc.

Comment: @shmosel I will look into that. Thank you.

Comment: "i am really tired of always creating an overloading method for every method which accepts a List" then don't: provide only a method accepting `List`, and put the burden of calling it for an array onto the client.

Comment: @DavidPaulo Sure, but why put yourself through so much hassle, put the burden onto the user of the API instead of yourself

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is because i am the main user of the API, so the burden is already with me. It is an auxiliary method, and sometimes i have to work with Arrays that comes from other libraries.

Comment: @DavidPaulo Okay, so? You have an API which requires a `Collection`, you currently have an `array`, IMHO, I'd still focus on converting the array to a `List` outside of the API. As JoeC has already pointed out, there is little overhead with using `Arrays.asList`. This is just my feeling on the subject and you are free to follow what ever direction you want, but I just see you making a lot more work for yourself which is adding very little overall benefit - again, just MHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't know of `Arrays.asList` time complexity, i am looking further into that. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidPaulo From what I remember, `Arrays.asList` just generates a `List` implementation which is backed by the supplied array, so it provides direct access to the array via the `List` API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know about wrapping an array on a list using `Arrays.asList` method, i thought it would copy the array into a list. `Arrays.asList` is a O(1) algorithm, as the good people in the comments told me.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is truly so critical that you cannot afford to wrap an array in an `ArrayList`, then you need to write separate algorithms for arrays and collections. It's really that simple.

The benefits of polymorphism rest on the assumption that you can afford to trade off a few microseconds to get shorter and more readable code. If you can't afford that, you can't have the convenience.